# Transforming irregular data into a structured table with Perl

Tags: perl, transform

I would like to transform the following lines of data into a structured table with perl:

```
3=884|4=884|5=MBREFUSDCMR|25=113500|824=20120229|387=4.15|248=TLD|280=5
3=884|4=884|5=MBREFUSDCMR|24=1|12=0|10=0|25=113500|824=20120229|280=5
3=884|4=884|5=MBREFUSDCMR|24=1|270=252304|280=5
```

Each value before the equal sign represents the identifier of the
corresponding value. Now I like to produce a table for further
analysis. The first row should include the identifiers and below their values. There is an unequal amount of identifiers in the
three rows which have to be kept in mind. Missing values should be
filled with the string "NA". So it should look like this

```
3|4|5|24|12|10|25|824|387|248|270|280
884|884|MBREFUSDCMR|NA|NA|NA|113500|20120229|4.15|TLD|NA|5
884|884|MBREFUSDCMR|1|0|0|113500|20120229|NA|NA|NA|5
884|884|MBREFUSDCMR|1|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|252304|5
```

@DVK

My approach was to first get all the variables. That would be the header/first row for the table. E.g.

```
my @data_dirty = <STDIN>;
chomp(@data_dirty);

## get the columns names
my ( @tmp, @var );
foreach my $j (@data_dirty) {
    foreach my $i (split /\|/, $j) {
    $i =~ s/\[.*\]//g;
    $i =~ s/\s+//g;
    $i =~ s/(.*)=.*/$1/g;
    push(@tmp, $i);
    }
}
@var = uniq @tmp;
```

Afterwards I might check each row if the variable in `@var` exists, if yes write the corresponding value otherwise write an "NA". However, I had some troubles with the checks and the correct storing of the data so that afterwards the output looks as desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to addressing such needs is to divide and conquer. A careful choice of subroutines is all you need.

Here, data needs to be loaded and all identifiers need to be known a priori before any table is printed.

The example below doesn't order the columns by their sequence of appearance (left as an exercise for the reader):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ( $data, $headers ) = load_data( 'tabular_data.txt' );

print_tabular( $data, $headers );

sub load_data {

    my ( $file ) = @_;

    open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;

    my ( @records, %fields );
    while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {

        chomp $line;

        my @columns = split /\|/, $line;               # Get columns
        my %entries = map { split /=/, $_ } @columns;  # Populate record,
                                                       # keys = fields
        push @records, \%entries;                      # Add to data collection

        $fields{$_}++ for keys %entries;               # Detect new headers
    }

    close $fh;

    return ( \@records, [ keys %fields ] );
}

sub print_tabular {

    my ( $data, $headers ) = @_;

    pretty_print( @$headers );

    for my $record ( @$data ) {
        my @values = map { exists $record->{$_}  # exists check needed...
                             ? $record->{$_}     # ... otherwise header '0'
                             : 'NA'              # ... would always print 'NA'
                         } @$headers;
        pretty_print( @values );
    }
}

sub pretty_print { print join( '|', @_ ), "\n" }
```

Comment: Note the trouble of preserving the original order of the headers.

Comment: @TLP : That I'll leave as an exercise for the reader. It's doable for sure... if order matters then push the headers to `@array` and run it through `List::MoreUtils::uniq` before returning it

Comment: I tried that, it didn't seem to work. Besides, you cannot make uniq know where to insert missing headers.

Comment: @TLP : On closer inspection, you're right. The `uniq` suggestion would work if the order was on an as-it-appears basis. I'd just write another sub to handle the ordering for me though.

Comment: You'd risk running into unsolvable problems, though. If `a,b,1` and `a,b,2` both appear, and no line has both 1 and 2, you'd never know their order. I suspect there is no guaranteed solution for that. Interesting problem.